# Scan with lastEvaluatedKey for DynamoDB though AWS API Gateway integration template

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

I was using AWS APIGateway integration templates to scan dynamoDB direclty instead of writing a separate lambda to handle request/response. But, the scan has limitation of 1MB and its causing scans to be limited partial data.

As per documentation, we should be doing the rescan until we find a match or through the complete table using lastEvaluatedKey. Is there any way I can use the lastEvaluatedKey and do rescan in the Gateway configuration itself instead of writing a lambda?

Thanks.

Comment: Curious, why no lambda? DynamoDB returned the result of a scan, with lastEvaluatedKey? can't you just include that in your next request?

Comment: I was trying to avoid writing and deploying a lambda if gateway can handle the requests. It does for query but scan has this limitation. DynamoDB did return lastEvaluated key. But, gateway reached the method response stage by that time. Is there any way I can trigger another request from that stage before gateway returns response to client?

Answer (score 1):

The trick lies on the request and response templates. This example enables the scan using `page_size` and `last_key` as input parameters (GET):

Request Template (application/json):

```yaml
#set($last_key = $input.params('last_key'))
#set($page_size = $input.params('page_size'))
{
#if($last_key != '')
  "ExclusiveStartKey": {
    "id": {
      "S": "$last_key"
    }
  },
#end
#if($page_size != '')
  "Limit": $page_size,
#end
  "TableName": "<your_table>"
}
```

Request Template (application/json):

```yaml
#set($payload = $input.path('$'))
#set($last_key = $payload.LastEvaluatedKey.id.S)
{
  "page_size": $payload.Count,
#if($last_key != '')
  "last_key": "$last_key",
#end
  "Items": $payload.Items
}
```

In case you're using CloudFormation, use this template:

```yaml
/er/tickets/scan:
  get:
    responses:
      "200": {}
    x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
      passthroughBehavior: WHEN_NO_TEMPLATES
      httpMethod: POST # must be POST even for GET
      type: AWS
      credentials:  !GetAtt ApiGatewayRole.Arn
      uri: !Sub "arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:dynamodb:action/Scan"
      requestTemplates:
        application/json: !Sub |
          #set($last_key = $input.params('last_key'))
          #set($page_size = $input.params('page_size'))
          {
          #if($last_key != '')
            "ExclusiveStartKey": {
              "id": {
                "S": "$last_key"
              }
            },
          #end
          #if($page_size != '')
            "Limit": $page_size,
          #end
            "TableName": "${TicketsTable}"
          }
      responses:
        default:
          statusCode: 200
          responseTemplates:
            application/json: |
              #set($payload = $input.path('$'))
              #set($last_key = $payload.LastEvaluatedKey.id.S)
              {
                "page_size": $payload.Count,
              #if($last_key != '')
                "last_key": "$last_key",
              #end
                "Items": $payload.Items
              }
```