# How to pass 'LastEvaluatedKey' in AWS API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to fetch the AWS DynamoDB records from the AWS API Gateway service.
Able to get records for the Scan with some filter options.

EX:
There are 10K records for the filter options but getting from AWS API response is only 50+ records.
How can I get the remaining data?

Reference like: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-amazon-api-gateway-as-a-proxy-for-dynamodb/

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass it as `ExclusiveStartKey` like in this template example (application/json):

```yaml
#set($last_key = $input.params('last_key'))
#set($page_size = $input.params('page_size'))
{
#if($last_key != '')
  "ExclusiveStartKey": {
    "id": {
      "S": "$last_key"
    }
  },
#end
#if($page_size != '')
  "Limit": $page_size,
#end
  "TableName": "<your_table>"
}
```

Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73613812/2197207) for a deeper explanation