# What is best way to approach pagination in aws lambda?

Tags: rest, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have a GET request that simply is handled by lambda which reads all the rows from dynamodb table. So it returns all records.

But when I have a very large amount of records there, it times out because doing scan on this table takes more than 29 seconds.

What is the best way to handle this, pagination ? If so, what would be the best way to do it?

Im using nodejs v3 sdk.

Comment: Using a Scan on a mostly DynamoDB defeats the purpose of having a DynamoDB, you should rethink that operation. Anyway https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html: *"If the total number of scanned items exceeds the maximum dataset size limit of 1 MB, the scan stops and results are returned to the user as a LastEvaluatedKey value to continue the scan in a subsequent operation."* - you must already implement / handle the pagination of dynamodb itself somewhere. Just change the way you do that pagination resolution.

Comment: It's just technical debt, I know it's used badly. I think you missed my point, the key here is that my lambda times out (29sec) because it can't manage to calculate all the things, so paginating inside just won't fix things. Should I modify this api to have this limit and offset in api query params for example itself ?

Comment: No, you missed my point: dynamodb already paginates, you have code in place that resolves that pagination fully. As you detected you must not do that due to the timeouts. The solutions is: expose the pagination to the user of your API via the LastEvaluatedKey or remove the need for pagination by hard limiting the number of items you return.

Comment: ok, so I guess I should use Optional ExclusiveStartKey, from ScanCommandInput combined with Limit paremeter.

Comment: Not sure if the Limit parameter is needed in your case. You could e.g. perform 50 Scan operations during each API call to your lambda, aggregate the responses of the 50 scans and return those alongside the last `LastEvaluatedKey` and on the next API call resume from that key and do 50 scans again. If 50 is too many for 29s maybe do 10. Or if your client is not bothered by performing too many request you could just return after a single scan. Really depends on what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Since dynamo db query operation returns data up to 1 mb, the pagination logic would be as follows:

1. query the table using ExclusiveStartKey and Limit parameters in a loop
2. from 2nd execution onwards set ExclusiveStartKey = LastEvaluatedKey
3. store the each query result
4. keep on looping until query result length returns 0

some additional consideration - 1) Increase the lambda timeout 2) increase lambda memory as well.

p.s. I am not familiar much with Node JS, excuse my ignorance.

Comment: I think you missed my point, the key here is that my lambda times out (29sec) because it can't manage to calculate all the things, so paginating inside just won't fix things. Should I modify this api to have this limit and offset in api query itself ?

Comment: certainly I missed your point and focused on pagination instead. Since API is getting timeout , you can invoke lambda asynchronously. API will not timeout, but will not return any result either,  as lambda will be working in the backend.  [Link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-integration-async.html) . Finally it depends on the architecture - how are you going to use/display the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your own page size by passing `Limit` along with your table name. Here is an example with 20 results per page:

```json
{
  "TableName": "your_dynamodb_table",
  "Limit": 20
}
```

Then, you'll have to pass `LastEvaluatedKey` from the resulting payload to get the next page, renamed as `ExclusiveStartKey`. This example assumes your key is of string type:

```json
{
  "TableName": "<your_dynamodb_table>",
  "Limit": 20,
  "ExclusiveStartKey": {
    "id": {"S": "<last_evaluated_key>"}
  }
}
```

Also, mind that you can access DynamoDB from API Gateway directly not having a lambda in-between. Like in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73613812/2197207).